# Dynamically add attributes to Laravel Blade components

Tags: laravel, components

I'm programatically building a form using Blade components and I can't find how to add attributes dynamically.

For example, I have an `$attribute` variable that contains `['data-id' => 123, 'step' => 0.01]`. I want to integrate it to my `form-number` component so that the final result is equivalent to:
`<x-form-number data-id="123" step="0.01" />`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I just found that you can pass an array as dynamic attributes so long as you wrap them in a `ComponentAttributeBag` instance like this:

```
<x-form-number :attributes="new Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag($attributes)" />
```

Now inside your component you will have your `$attributes` array, just as if you had passed them in individually!

Answer (score -1):

```
<x-form-number :data-id="$attribute['data-id']" :step="$attribute['step']" />
```

from the doc

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components

> The keys in the array are dynamic. I don’t know them in advance

Sure you know them in advance they are defined in your class. So you just have to popultae your array with all the keys (with defaut value accepted by your class)

Comment: The keys in the array are dynamic. I don’t know them in advance.

Comment: Sure you know them in advance they are defined in your class. So you just have to popultae your array with all the keys (with defaut value accepted by your class)

Comment: `$values = array_values( $array);
echo $values[0];`

Comment: @Dri372 But you might not. If this is a dynamic component, you never know what's going to be added. For example, and <input> might have `maxlength=#`, `minlength=#` `required`... a lot of attributes you wouldn't want to manually setup for just in case they're used.